# How can I check minlength and restrict special characters with Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Good afternoon or at least in my country ^_^

I'm basically trying to do a full validation before submitting a form using the Vue Js library, on this snippet I'm checking if a input is empty.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: null
  },
  methods:{
    checkForm: function (e) {
      if (this.name) {
        return true;
      }

      if (!this.name) {
        console.log("Please write your name :)")
      }
      
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form id="app" @submit="checkForm" method="post">
<input type="text" v-model="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

As you can see it works. But I want to increase security by adding a restriction for special characters and also detect a minlenght.

I try to search the internet for functions that allow me to do what I am looking for. But I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@catawP, i edited your snippet to allow checking for length and for special characters.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: null,
    email: null
  },
  methods:{
    checkForm: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // if you want to check both fields
      if(this.checkField(this.name, 'name') && this.checkField(this.email, 'email')) return true
      // if you want to check only one field
      if(this.checkField(this.email, 'email')) return true
     
    },
    checkField(value, field){
      if (value) {
        if(value.length < 10 && field === 'name'){ // check the length only for name field
          console.log("The " + field + " should contain at least 10 characters!")
        }else if(/[;,.]/.test(value) && field !== 'email'){ // exclude email field from this check
          console.log('No special characters are allowed')
        }else if(field === 'email' && !this.email.includes('@')){ // ex of custom checks for a specific field
          console.log('Email field should contain @')
        }else{
          return true;
        }
      }

      if (!value) {
        console.log("Please write your " + field + " :)")
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form id="app" @submit="checkForm" method="post">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" v-model="name" id="name">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" v-model="email" id="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for, Very thankful. Have nice day

Comment: @catawP I have a little doubt, if you can give me something it would be great, If I would add a new input and I only want check if the new input is empty using your example. How I should do it, because I add one more to check and the vue dont require the two inputs with text.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right, but I updated the answer with options for handling multiple inputs, and custom validation for specific inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the length can be done with the .length property. So you could add:

```
if(this.name.length < 30) {
   console.log('Name must have 30 characters or more.');
}
```

Of course you don't want to use console.log for your form validation, but you did above in your first check so I repeated it. Also, 30 was arbitrary, you would change that to what you want.

As for "special characters", what do you mean? Do you want to disallow certain characters or only allow some characters? If you want to disallow some characters, you could use a regular expression and use `test` to see if it exists. For example:

```
let badchrs = /[$%\^]/;
if(badchrs.test(this.name)) {
    console.log("you can't use $ or % or ^");
}
```

To only allow letters, you could do like so:

```
s = 'raymond';
badchrs = /^[a-z]/;
console.log(badchrs.test(s));
```

Comment: Thanks for you support :)